# How does render work in ReactJS with those HTML tags being "returned"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React code I see `return (<form> .. </form>);` with HTML inside... is this valid Javascript? Is it somehow converted to a string or something?

I am learning Javascript right now and certainly have some gaps. This puzzles me how this is done though!

```
var AddTodoComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" disabled={AppStore.isSaving()}/>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Look at he examples in the documentation and click on the "Compiled JS" tab: http://facebook.github.io/react/ .

Answer (score 6):

This syntax is called [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).  It is not normally valid JavaScript in the sense that your browser will probably not pick it up, but with a transpiler you can achieve proper JavaScript.

In the link above, you'll also see how to write valid JavaScript right off the bat, avoiding the JSX syntax.(which is what the transpiler would produce).

The following sample is from Facebook's [JSX in Depth guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) linked above

```
var Nav, Profile;
// Input (JSX):
var app = <Nav color="blue"><Profile>click</Profile></Nav>;
// Output (JS):
var app = React.createElement(
  Nav,
  {color:"blue"},
  React.createElement(Profile, null, "click")
);
```

As you can see, in the output section, React defines a method which performs the render for you, `React.createElement`

Comment: Yep! Explore the other pages on the linked website.  They contain such a vast knowledge of React (there really isn't too much to know technically).  I spent my first week with React just reading a few of those a day and then applying the knowledge to my app.

Comment: Yes. I am working hard to really learn Javascript. I am very interested in React and what React Native is doing. So I am planning on learning React right along side learning pure JS.

Comment: How does that transpiler kick off? I seem to be able to write the jsx and the page renders. Is there overhead with this transpiler?

Comment: You call it from a command line like any other.  I use TypeScript, but babel is another option.  There is a [guide in the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) showing how to use babel to do it.